# Restrict orientation change on page level

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

How do I restrict orientation change to portrait on the first page but not second page?

Im working on Windows 8.1 store app.

Answer (score 0):

Set [`DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().AutoRotationPreferences`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.autorotationpreferences.aspx) when you navigate to the page you don't want to rotate. Set it again when you navigate to the page you do want to rotate.